# rasterio - mask raster against shape, with all pixels completely inside shape

Tags: python, geospatial, postgis, rasterio

I'm cutting a tiff file against a given shape, to filter the pixels inside.

I'm using rasterio to do it like this:

`mask = rasterio.mask.mask(tiff, geoms, crop=True, all_touched=False)`

This works but doesn't yield exactly what I want (which is: give me only the pixels that are **completely inside** the shape).

[image: what i want]
[see bigger picture](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YcSYD_IKKRbut1rEfrDclJaPnMTa0yNuMSEHR44YVVM5l57LWEHQ1b-SehzQKAb44Z7FN_SfqlItIsPc-kWCu4LTihppQVnRq91NreO-jczwsk2Kgv2TJzePe3wpSIe-EqbaEM0l52MJXgVC6GD0-nOynnhnA_gS3npH9lN_rHZxLw_Pm5f2LDfNIzsX9ocyFNHSoJPw2AfNTOarxBmxSgNFxDZ6uUQ6OZi5XYpZsCS6ScHRNux7wbl93uZQ77qDfSpA4IYp_iFxPaVLBYfHrtX-qRFAfq93fxcvnanS2VQ8LNHhmLDZBmyEO0f_PomqkReKuWRNPy70ZNMddaYg4dThonAF9Oj8Tm7a8KKQvahotQshsnP-qOaZIvDfF9MsOjF6swgWi15KoBmqYULQ0JclM9nyS1eJuv6wbUMmy9rurRDN_1bRTDZbRHWAK62N3VTbW-_UQaKtaFVErBIgLoIiXSCGk01zPMbST7_Lei0wvehpcPVwKsmxh7sQs57rqr_BxgBa8xnswvCW3oxv43JO7kAaw6ubLBori_MYsx43id1hzo3riu8oPq_56RgBi06SvHC_JbO9iUgrWFAzhl1erFcfkifX_37te5rPUsG8OOFqBSzT6A=w1705-h959-no)

So, what `all_touched=False` does is, according to [the docs](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/api/rasterio.mask.html), that it restricts the criteria from `all_touched=True` (fig. 1) by only including pixels that have **its center** inside the shape (fig. 2).

How can I select only the pixels that are completely inside the shape (like in fig. 3)?